# Scope Issues with \renewcommand inside \newcommand

Tags: environments

I am creating an environment so I can write a book containing information all formatted the same way based on the environment template. Eventually, I would like to be able to write

```
\begin{eqdescription}
    \eqname{Bob Doe}
    \eqcolor{Blue}
    \eqnotes{Bob will help you.}
\end{eqdescription}
\begin{eqdescription}
    \eqname{Jim Doe}
    \eqnotes{Jim will NOT help you.}
\end{eqdescription}
```

and have entry formatted nicely and in the same way based on the environment `eqdescription` by doing something like this:

```
\newenvironment{eqdescription}{}{%
    \section{\eqnameval}

    Favorite Color: \eqcolorval

    Notes: \eqnotesval
    }
```

Because Jim Doe doesn't have a favorite color, his is blank so I thought his would show up with some default value, like `no favorite color`.

I thought that defining some commands to initialize and set the values inside an environment would be easy like this:

```
\newcommand{\initcommand}[2]{%
    % Set the Default Value:
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname eq#1val\endcsname[0]{#2} 
    % Make a command \eq[name]{[avalue]} that sets it in the future.
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname eq#1\endcsname [1] {%
        \expandafter\renewcommand\csname eq#1val \endcsname[0]{##1} 
    }                       
}
```

And that at the top of the environment I could put:

```
\initcommand{notes}{Default Value.}
\initcommand{name}{No Name.}
\initcommand{color}{No favorite color.}
```

But not only does the initcommand fail, this causes all kinds of issues with redefining values.

Is there  a concise way to define little templates like this without convoluted syntax and duplicate code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could `g`lobally `def`ine the defaults at the start of `eqdescription`, and then `\renewcommand` them inside the environment whenever you call `\eqname`, `\eqcolor` or `\eqnotes`. The `\gdef` will redefine whatever already exists. `\renewcommand` will have a local scope, but does require the definitions be defined. This is not a problem as you're defining them with `\begin{eqdescription}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\eqname}{\renewcommand\eqnameval}
\newcommand{\eqcolor}{\renewcommand\eqcolorval}
\newcommand{\eqnotes}{\renewcommand\eqnotesval}

\newenvironment{eqdescription}
  {% Set defaults for this environment
   \gdef\eqnameval{No name.}%
   \gdef\eqcolorval{No favourite colour.}%
   \gdef\eqnotesval{Default value.}%
  }
  {%
    \section{\eqnameval}

    Favorite Color: \eqcolorval

    Notes: \eqnotesval%
  }

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{eqdescription}
  \eqname{Bob Doe}
  \eqcolor{Blue}
  \eqnotes{Bob will help you.}
\end{eqdescription}
\begin{eqdescription}
  \eqname{Jim Doe}
  \eqnotes{Jim will NOT help you.}
\end{eqdescription}

\end{document}
```